# Edit the display of view on drupal 8

Tags: views, entities, 8, theming

Currently working on theming with Twig
I created a region called 'Blog Content'
I placed under it a view that i recently created Called 'Blog' with a display Block to display just the 3 last article**

for each field I specified the wrapper around it and the CSS class used by my theme and I have this output:

[image]

But i want it to be just like this:

[image]

**My questions:**

1. How to specify the tag (html) to be used to display my field with specific css class : in my case i want to display the title with
2. What field should i add to add the date of post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Edit your field on which you want to add an HTML tag to a specific class.(Style settings category)
   See screenshot. [image]
2. You need to add "Authored on" field and configure the display as you want to be shown.
   [image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer it was a year and a half ago . It was resolved i think i used the same method you gave. The website is live since that ngtrend.com